# How to capture HTTP Requests from a specific application

Tags: http, websocket, fiddler, packet-sniffers

I am trying to capture HTTP and Websocket requests from a Jackbox Party Pack, but when using fiddler classic and fiddler everywhere it only captures web browser request!

Is there a way to make fiddler capture these packets from Jackbox or is there another piece of software that can do the tick!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Fiddler is an HTTP proxy, if the game uses raw TCP connections or UDP connections is can not capture them as it is not HTTP traffic. If you want to capture all traffic use Wireshark.

Comment: Jackbox uses HTTP with WS and not TCP or UDP by themselves

Comment: WebSocket bases on HTTP but it requires special support in the proxy if you want to intercept it's data.  I don't lnow if WebSockets are supported by Fiddle Classic or Everywhere. The only proxy I know for sure that has WebSocket support is Mitmproxy.

Comment: I know fiddler classic has websocket support, not sure about everywhere